# Проблема с эфектом

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня. При использовании анимации jquery ui столкнулся с багом:

```
$(this).effect("shake", { times: 2, direction: 'left', distance: 6 }, 300);
```

Иногда крашит верстку, сверху и снизу при воспроизведении эффекта.

Кто-то уже встречался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:absolute; z-index:1000;` для блока сделайте